# Flutter: ListView.builder pagination page refresh when adding more items to the list

Tags: android, flutter, dart, provider

I have a ListView.builder widget which returns a list view which is coming from an API. This API has pagination so I added a scroll listener to listen to scroll to the bottom of the first page items and then call the API to load next page data.

```
  void _scrollListener() {
if (controller.position.maxScrollExtent == controller.position.pixels) {
  loadMoreData();
}}
```

I use provider as my state management method. So when I need to load more data , the app call the API which is in the provider model and add the data a list(the list which builds the ListView.buider) .

```
Container(
        child: AbsorbPointer(
      absorbing: contactsModel.isLoading,
      child: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
                padding:
                    EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0, left: 22.0, right: 22.0),
                width: w,
                child: searchPeopleField),
            Expanded(
              child: !contactsModel.isLoading
                  ? Stack(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          child: contactsModel.allContacts.isNotEmpty
                              ? ListView.separated(
                                  controller: controller,
                                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                                  separatorBuilder:
                                      (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                                          Divider(
                                              height: 3,
                                              color: kBlack029,
                                              indent: 20,
                                              endIndent: 20),
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                                  itemCount:
                                      contactsModel.allContacts.length,
                                  itemBuilder:
                                      (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                    return contactListView(
                                        context,
                                        index,
                                        contactsModel.allContacts,
                                        flag,
                                        baseUrl,
                                        urlLoad,
                                        widget.isFromAct,
                                        highlightText);
                                  })
                              : Center(
                                  child: contactsModel.isFromSearch
                                      ? UpsNoData()
                                      : noAPIData(w, h),
                                ),
                        ),
                        Visibility(
                            visible: contactsModel.isLoading,
                            child: Center(
                              child: progressIndicator(h),
                            )
                        )
                      ],
                    )
                  : Center(child: progressIndicator(h)),
            ),
```

This is how my UI works for this function. My problem is when I scroll down and load more data it adds next page data to the list. But it refreshes the page and goes back to the top of the list. See the below video.

[click to see video(GIF)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6afSg.jpg)

How can I solve this? I want to list to be able to scroll from where it started to load more data.

```
  paginatingContactsList(context,step) async {
checkNetworkStatus(context).then((value) async {
  if (value == true) {
    isLoading = true;
    notifyListeners();
    await paginateContactsData(http.Client(), context,step).then((res) {
      resData = res;
      if(res != null && res.data != null) {
        for(var items in res.data){
          allContacts.add(items);
        }
      }
      isLoading = false;
      notifyListeners();
    });
    isFromSearch = false;
    notifyListeners();
  } else {
    Toast.show('Offline'.tr(), context,
        duration: 2, backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent);
  }
});
```

}

Comment: can you please add loadMoreData function here, so that will be easy to understand.

Comment: @Mudasirsyed the load more function is added to the question. Thanks.